# can't run the emulator in android studio 2.0

Tags: android-studio

I wan't to use the camera in my application but when I ran the emulator it shows this:

[image]

And this is my setting:

[image]

Comment: Does your graphics card support OpenGL 2.1? Also if you could state how much VRAM your System has if would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Right-click on the Desktop and click Nvidia Control Panel. Click
   Manage 3D settings. Click Program Settings. Select SketchUp from the
   drop-down list. There are five settings that you need to configure:

- Anisotropic Filtering set to Application Controlled.
- Antialiasing FxAA set to On.
- Antialiasing Gamma set to On.
- Antialiasing Mode set to Application Controlled.
- Open GL set to the name of the video card that you have.

This might remedy the situation where you have incorrect OpenGL settings. However if you have an old card with a small amount of VRAM you might unfortunately be unable to run the emulator of that system.